# Protecting clock from hacking

Tags: sensor, clock, security

We are working with an Raspberry Pi project where the time precision is very important.

Money could be potentially lost if the clock is compromised.

How would you build a tamper-safe clock module?

Comment: What kind of a clock are we talking about here?  Real time or core clock?  How accurate does it need to be?  And what sort of tampering does it need to be resistant against?

Comment: Beware, the PI is a dev board targeted at educational market. See their FAQ at *Can you test it to make sure that it is suitable for <X>*. Using it for production projects where lot of money is involved might be not so wise. Are you sure that the PI is better suited for your project than a regular mini-computer with a regular RTC (Intel NUC, Fit-PC etc..)? That being said, you could use an USB radio clock receiver, and check the time you get by network and the time you get by radio are the same.

Comment: How tamper-safe? Bored guy with non-root SSH access safe, or really motivated hacker with an EE-lab safe?

Comment: Does the person doing the potential tampering have physical access to the device? What action should occur if the device detects tampering?

Comment: What is the consequence of false positives?

Comment: Compare the design of SecureID tokens: http://www.embedded.com/design/other/4005693/Under-the-hood-SecurID-fob-single-chip-safety-net : epoxy sealing is standard tamperproofing, but will almost certainly give your Pi overheating problems.

Comment: @martinm: nice idea.

Comment: @Connor Wolf, motivated hacker it is

Comment: @RedGritty: Yeah, it will be a point of sale allowing offline transactions. delete the data and block the device with a "was tampered" message.

Comment: @user36129: lost data. but it's acceptable.

Comment: @pjc50: yeah heating would make a mess.

Comment: If you're against a motivated hacker, you're SOL. Run it on a remote server. Physical access = inevitable ownage, with sufficient motivation.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: thank you Connor. I forgot to add a consideration, such equipment is checked once every week at least. which in some way limits temporally to the attacker.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to design a hardware module which repeatedly outputs the number of milliseconds (or microseconds, or seconds, or whatever) since it has been powered on, and the number of times it has been powered on.  If the device repeatedly outputs the time since startup and number of times it has been started, and doesn't accept any input from the Raspberry Pi, there would be no way for anything to tamper with the time since there would be no way for the Pi to do communicate with the device in any way.  An alternative would be to have the hardware module connect with some device separate from the Pi and allow the time to be set by that external device.  Cutting power to the device would disrupt time-keeping, but the next time the device is powered on its startup count would be changed.

If one wants to protect the device against physical tampering once it has been "started", one could use an external device to load a private signing key into RAM, and have the device sign all of its time reports.  If after the person who loads the private key has left someone else tries to alter the device, it would be impossible for someone who doesn't know the private key to alter the device without losing the private key.  Note, however, that such an approach would add security against setting the time forward but not against setting the time backward, since someone could capture the signed time data output by the device and build a fake device to replay that old data.  For security against physical tampering that would set time forward or backward, one would need to use a bidirectional communications path and have the device accept tokens, combine with time stamps, and sign them.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider implementing [Precision Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) (a.k.a. IEEE-1588) on your RPi, and using a physically secure machine as your master clock.

I don't know offhand if PTP supports crypographic signatures on its messages to protect against spoofing, but you could add them if it doesn't — or run it through an `ssh` tunnel.